# Groovy Calll Function Dynamically

Tags: function, groovy, dynamic, jenkins-groovy

I want to store the function name of each object in a hash map and be able to call it based on its name (string).

For example in python i'm able to perform the next:

```
def function_1(a1, a2, a3):
    return a1+a2+a3
def function_2(a1, a2, a3):
    return a3-a2-a1
def function_3(a1, a2, a3):
    return a1*a2*a3

for func in ['function_1', 'function_2', 'function_3']:
    result = globals()[func](arg1, arg2, arg3)
    print (result)
```

does something like this is possible in groovy (something like using the globals in python)? i want to be able to store the functions names as string in somewhere...

and no, i don't want to use classes here

Answer (score 0):

You could declare methods

```
def function_1(a1, a2, a3) {
    a1+a2+a3
}

...
```

Or closures

```
def function_1 = {a1, a2, a3 ->
    a1+a2+a3
}

...
```

Then do

```
['function_1', 'function_2', 'function_3'].each { func ->
    def result = "$func"(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    println result
}
```

Comment: hell yeah! thanks!!!!!!   now, why  it doesnt work just by calling "$function_1"(1,2,3)? by just calling the function directly from string im receiving "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: function_1 for class: WorkflowScript" (just intersting)

Comment: The `$` is for string templating. You can omit it and call with `"function_1"(...` but then you may as well just use a regular method call `function_1(...`